# How to hide/remove slider ticks/steps and their labels in plotly.js?

Tags: javascript, css, plotly, plotly.js

Is it possible to remove or hide the animation slider's step ticks and labels? I would like to remove the slider step markers (ticks) and their labels: 'Red', 'Green' and 'Blue' from underneath the slider.

**However still keeping the current frame/step label displayed.** (Above slider on right side)

Preferably would like to be able to do it with plotly's layout configuration but if it's possible to hide via CSS rules I'm all ears.

The example below is taken directly from their sample page here: https://codepen.io/plotly/pen/NbKmmQ

```js
Plotly.plot('graph', {
 data: [{
   x: [1, 2, 3],
   y: [2, 1, 3],
   line: {
     color: 'red',
     simplify: false,
   }
 }],
 layout: {
   sliders: [{
     pad: {t: 30},
     x: 0.05,
     len: 0.95,
     currentvalue: {
       xanchor: 'right',
       prefix: 'color: ',
       font: {
         color: '#888',
         size: 20
       }
     },
     transition: {duration: 500},
     // By default, animate commands are bound to the most recently animated frame:
     steps: [{
       label: 'red',
       method: 'animate',
       args: [['red'], {
         mode: 'immediate',
         frame: {redraw: false, duration: 500},
         transition: {duration: 500}
       }]
     }, {
       label: 'green',
       method: 'animate',
       args: [['green'], {
         mode: 'immediate',
         frame: {redraw: false, duration: 500},
         transition: {duration: 500}
       }]
     }, {
       label: 'blue',
       method: 'animate',
       args: [['blue'], {
         mode: 'immediate',
         frame: {redraw: false, duration: 500},
         transition: {duration: 500}
       }]
     }]
   }],
   updatemenus: [{
     type: 'buttons',
     showactive: false,
     x: 0.05,
     y: 0,
     xanchor: 'right',
     yanchor: 'top',
     direction: 'left',
     pad: {t: 60, r: 20},
     buttons: [{
       label: 'Play',
       method: 'animate',
       args: [null, {
         fromcurrent: true,
         frame: {redraw: false, duration: 1000},
         transition: {duration: 500}
       }]
     }, {
       label: 'Pause',
       method: 'animate',
       args: [[null], {
         mode: 'immediate',
         frame: {redraw: false, duration: 0}
       }]
     }]
   }]
 },
 // The slider itself does not contain any notion of timing, so animating a slider
 // must be accomplished through a sequence of frames. Here we'll change the color
 // and the data of a single trace:
 frames: [{
   name: 'red',
   data: [{
     y: [2, 1, 3],
     'line.color': 'red'
   }]
 }, {
   name: 'green',
   data: [{
     y: [3, 2, 1],
     'line.color': 'green'}]
 }, {
   name: 'blue',
   data: [{
     y: [1, 3, 2],
     'line.color': 'blue'}]
 }]
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#graph {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="graph"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there is no property in the [`official docs`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/), So please consider this alternate, where we set the `tickcolor` and `font.color` of the slider label and tick as white, which is same as the background.

The properties that do this, are shown below.

```
tickcolor: 'white',
font: {
  color: 'white'
}
```

```js
Plotly.plot('graph', {
  data: [{
    x: [1, 2, 3],
    y: [2, 1, 3],
    line: {
      color: 'red',
      simplify: false,
    }
  }],
  layout: {
    sliders: [{
      pad: {
        t: 30
      },
      x: 0.05,
      len: 0.95,
      currentvalue: {
        xanchor: 'right',
        prefix: 'color: ',
        font: {
          color: '#888',
          size: 20
        }
      },
      transition: {
        duration: 500
      },
      tickcolor: 'white',
      font: {
        color: 'white'
      },
      // By default, animate commands are bound to the most recently animated frame:
      steps: [{
        label: 'red',
        method: 'animate',
        args: [
          ['red'], {
            mode: 'immediate',
            frame: {
              redraw: false,
              duration: 500
            },
            transition: {
              duration: 500
            }
          }
        ]
      }, {
        label: 'green',
        method: 'animate',
        args: [
          ['green'], {
            mode: 'immediate',
            frame: {
              redraw: false,
              duration: 500
            },
            transition: {
              duration: 500
            }
          }
        ]
      }, {
        label: 'blue',
        method: 'animate',
        args: [
          ['blue'], {
            mode: 'immediate',
            frame: {
              redraw: false,
              duration: 500
            },
            transition: {
              duration: 500
            }
          }
        ]
      }]
    }],
    updatemenus: [{
      type: 'buttons',
      showactive: false,
      x: 0.05,
      y: 0,
      xanchor: 'right',
      yanchor: 'top',
      direction: 'left',
      pad: {
        t: 60,
        r: 20
      },
      buttons: [{
        label: 'Play',
        method: 'animate',
        args: [null, {
          fromcurrent: true,
          frame: {
            redraw: false,
            duration: 1000
          },
          transition: {
            duration: 500
          }
        }]
      }, {
        label: 'Pause',
        method: 'animate',
        args: [
          [null], {
            mode: 'immediate',
            frame: {
              redraw: false,
              duration: 0
            }
          }
        ]
      }]
    }]
  },
  // The slider itself does not contain any notion of timing, so animating a slider
  // must be accomplished through a sequence of frames. Here we'll change the color
  // and the data of a single trace:
  frames: [{
    name: 'red',
    data: [{
      y: [2, 1, 3],
      'line.color': 'red'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'green',
    data: [{
      y: [3, 2, 1],
      'line.color': 'green'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'blue',
    data: [{
      y: [1, 3, 2],
      'line.color': 'blue'
    }]
  }]
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#graph {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="graph"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks I ended up using: `transparent` for the colour properties.

Comment: @NarenMurali, this works but it hides 1) ticks 2) tick labels but also 3) the `currentvalue` display above the slider. How to have 1) 2) but not 3) ?

Comment: @Basj Hi, note that this solution does not require to set `label: ''`, the currentvalue will be displayed for every step having a non-empty label (here, the ticks and tick labels are made transparent, which does not affect the style of the currentvalue section). It seems like there is still no official way of doing this.